# Bind Xvfb on localhost rather than *

Tags: linux, port, x11

I am using Xvfb to run an a wine background application that needs a valid display.
It appears that it binds to *:x11.
For security reasons I would like to avoid opening any unnecessary ports.

Is there any way force Xvfb to bind to localhost rather than *?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, if I understand your need correctly you can just skip TCP altogether.

```
Xvfb :0 -nolisten tcp
```

Afterwards this works:

```
DISPLAY=:0
xterm
```

And you can check yourself with `netstat -ntlp | grep Xvfb` that Xvfb has no ports open.

Comment: Thanks, yes this seems to work fine. For some reason I thought it uses localhost by default, but now I assume it uses unix sockets - which makes perfect sense.