# How to disable Xvfb using TCP ports when using pyvirtualdisplay (Python)?

Tags: linux, port, python, tcp, xvfb

Trying to use `pyvirtualdisplay` for Python to start some applications with a virtual `Xvfb` X terminal.   However, we've seen port clashes and would like to disable `Xvfb` from using TCP ports.  I have read [this question about doing something very similar to this](https://serverfault.com/q/264481/144154), but I do not understand where this configuration should be set for it in order to work with `pyvirtualdisplay` (or as the default configuration otherwise).

Any help with this will be very appreciated.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyVirtualDisplay invokes the Xvfb program, but unfortunately it does not provide a way to configure sending parameters to that program.  If you want to pass the -nolisten tcp option to Xvfb with PyVirtualDisplay, you will have to edit the pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py file in the package.

At the bottom of the file is this section which defines the command and options:

```
@property
def _cmd(self):
    cmd = [PROGRAM,
           dict(black='-br', white='-wr')[self.bgcolor],
           '-screen',
           str(self.screen),
           'x'.join(map(str, list(self.size) + [self.color_depth])),
           self.new_display_var,
           ]
    return cmd
```

You'll need to modify it to be something like this:

```
@property
def _cmd(self):
    cmd = [PROGRAM,
           dict(black='-br', white='-wr')[self.bgcolor],
           '-screen',
           str(self.screen),
           'x'.join(map(str, list(self.size) + [self.color_depth])),
           self.new_display_var,
           '-nolisten',
           'tcp',
           ]
    return cmd
```

Comment: Wow.  I can't tell you what a lifesaver you are! Thanks a lot.  I'll add notes here if and when I can get back to this.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, this absolutely works.  No more TCP ports being used by `Xvfb` thanks!